# Connecting to small clock battery terminals

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to connect wire leads to small battery terminals. This is a battery terminal for a 1.5V AG13 battery in a small clock. My question is how to connect leads to it in an easy and non-destructive way. I’m considering soldering as well as some sort of clip. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Soldering, alligator clips, battery-sized bit of wood and tin foil contacts, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go to the store and purchase a wood dowel that is the same diameter as the AG13 battery. Then you can craft up a small pellet that has some small holes drilled at appropriate places and angles to insert small wires from your wire harness. The best termination of the wires would be to acquire some copper tape that has conductive adhesive and apply a couple of small pieces to the dowel side and face to mate with the contacts in the clock.

Do note that the wood dowel piece does not need to be as thin as the AG13 battery. It could be longer and even protrude some out from the back of the clock.

If you do not feel so much up to the task of DIY craftsmanship then I would suggest that you can just solder your wires directly to the contacts. This type of clock module is not so precious that you need to find a non-destructive manner to connect the wires.

Comment: Very creative this early in the morning.  I like the answer. The OP can always go back to batteries if need be.+

Comment: Creative idea — I like it. Are you assuming the dowel would simply be pressure fit into place?

Comment: @Kulluk007 - Since I saw nothing more than a picture I cannot suggest how the craft made battery replacement would be retained. In some cases there is a battery cover or door which keeps the battery in place. It that was the case then the craft made piece would be the size of the battery with the two wires emerging from the middle of the open face. Then a round hole in the center of the cover would let the wires come out.